# Wordpress parse error unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: wordpress

Mates, two days ago, the webhosting of a site i'm administrating went down.
Now it seems to be back working, but when I try to acces to wp-admin i recieve the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, 
expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in 
/home/ohmycut/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 80
```

These are lines from 75 to 85:

```
// Include the wpdb class and, if present, a db.php database drop-in.
require_wp_db();

// Set the database table prefix and the format specifiers for database table columns.
$GLOBALS['table_prefix'] = $table_prefix;
wp_set_wpdb_vars();

// Start the WordPress object cache, or an external object cache if the drop-in is present.
wp_start_object_cache();
```

I, honestly, don't understand why am i getting this error.
Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the web hosting service to see if they can revert it to a state before the service went down.